# Métodos de los arreglos y réplica su funcionamiento de manera lógica: map()

Tags: javascript, funciones, map

## Métodos de los arreglos y réplica su funcionamiento de manera lógica: map()

Debo replicar de manera lógica para que al invocar la función `map (arr, callback)`........ `map([1,2,3,4,5], (e)=>{return e * 10})`, me retorne:

```
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

Y si pongo `return e * 20` me siga dando otro resultado.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tal parece ser que intentas que alguien resuelva el ejercicio por ti. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado, mediante un [mcve]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo necesario, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

### Consideraciones

Partiendo del siguiente fragmento, cito:

> Debo replicar de manera lógica para que al invocar la función `map (arr, callback)`........ “`map([1,2,3,4,5], (e)=>{return e * 10})`...

Debo aclarar que [**`Array.prototype.map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) no es una función independiente. Es un método de *array* en JavaScript y su utilización sería la que sigue:

```js
const nuevoArray = array.map(function (value) {
  return value;
});
```

O expresado de otra manera, sería:

```js
const nuevoArray = array.map((value) => value);
```

Entonces, para lograr el objetivo planteado debes cambiar la siguiente línea:

```js
map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (e) => {
  return e * 10;
});
```

Por esta otra:

```js
const nuevoArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((e) => {
  return e * 10;
});

console.log(nuevoArray);
```

Donde `e` es el elemento del *array* que se recorre en cada iteración

### Actualización

Si lo que deseas es crear una función denominada `map()` que puedas llamar de la siguiente manera:

```js
map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (e) => {
  return e * 10;
});
```

Entonces, debes definirlo así:

```js
const map = (array, fn) => {
  return array.map(fn);
};
```

Donde `array` es el *array* de la función y `fn` es la función que pasa como parámetro. Por lo tanto su implementación completa sería:

```js
const map = (array, fn) => {
  return array.map(fn);
};

const nuevoArray = map([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], (e) => {
  return e * 10;
});

console.log(nuevoArray);
```

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, dejando muy claro que no es una función independiente. Bien explicado. Aunque, leyendo nuevamente, parece que quiere crear una función con el comportamiento del método. Hay que esperar a que aclare y agregue lo que ha intentado.

Comment: Gracias @Triby :). Voy a agregar una actualización tomando en cuenta lo que me has comentado.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero considera evitar dar respuesta a preguntas donde el OP no se ha interesado en hacer o mostrar ningún tipo de esfuerzo en resolver su problema. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En el callback de map que se ejecuta para cada elemento puedes multiplicar por una variable sea con valor 10 o 20.

### Código

```js
let lista=[1,2,3,4,5];
let mul=20;
console.log(lista.map((x)=>x*mul))
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero considera evitar dar respuesta a preguntas donde el OP no se ha interesado en hacer o mostrar ningún tipo de esfuerzo en resolver su problema. Saludos